# How can I LIMIT the number of rows that are UPDATED in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-limit

This UPDATE query crashed my website, I'm not sure why.

There are 39,000 rows to update, and the site crashed after 3,500 rows were updated.

Is there a way to LIMIT the UPDATE to executing say 2,500 UPDATES at a time. Or perhaps a more efficient way of doing it?

```
UPDATE database_2.user 
SET 
    usergroupid = 15
WHERE userid NOT IN 
(
    SELECT vBulletinId FROM database_1.Users
);
```

Thanks

Comment: *This UPDATE query crashed my website* Give more details - in general none MySQL operation may affect the website. Maximum - you may observe "timeout" because the operation is longer then MySQL answer wait time is set, and website code decides that MySQL hangs.

Comment: NOT IN is generally the worst option performance-wise. Try a LEFT JOIN exclusion join, or NOT EXISTS, both widely discussed

Answer (score 1):

A few tens of thousand rows is a really small volume for a relational database, and you should not face performance issues with this code, unless your hardware is severely undersized.

I would still recommend rewriting the query with `not exists`:

```
update database_2.user u2
set u2.usergroupid = 15
where not exists (select 1 from database_1.users u1 where u1.userid = u2.vBulletinId)
```

This is more efficient, and properly hande possible `null`  values in `vBulletinId`. For performance, you want an index on `database_1.users(vBulletinId)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use LIMIT operator in your select query.

Comment: **This is WRONG !!!** This will **increase** the amount of updated rows (`NOT IN` is used !!!), and it is possible that the rows which must stay unchanged will be updated.